# How do I make this VBA loop run faster?

Tags: excel, nested-loops, vba

This loop written for Excel takes ranges of 2 unique lists and searches for them in a table on a different sheet. Its a two column search, 2 values from the list must appear in a row for the accumulator to count. It works just fine but when I parse lots of data I can be waiting for minutes on end. I am looking for a way to make this loop much faster. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
Sub parseTwo(ByVal startRng As Range, ByVal findRng As Range, _
ByVal pasteStartRng As Range, ByVal strTitle As String, ByVal findTableColumn As String, _
ByVal startOffset As Integer, ByVal handledOffset As Integer, _
ByVal handledBool As Boolean)
'==========================================================================
'==========================================================================
'Turn off some Excel functionality so code runs faster
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
'==========================================================================
'==========================================================================
Dim x As Long           'Declare accumulator.
x = 0                   'Give x default value.
'==========================================================================
'==========================================================================
Dim firstLoop As Boolean 'Declare boolean value.
firstLoop = True         'Declare initial value of boolean as true.
'==========================================================================
'==========================================================================
Dim pasteFindRng As Range 'Set the paste range for "find" items.
Set pasteFindRng = pasteStartRng.Offset(1, -1
Dim pasteAccum As Range   'Set the paste range for the "accumulator".
Set pasteAccum = pasteStartRng.Offset(1, 0)
'==========================================================================
'==========================================================================
Dim initialFindRng As Range 'Keep track of the initial "find" range to reference it later.
Set initialFindRng = findRng
'==========================================================================
'==========================================================================
Do While startRng.Text <> vbNullString             'Do while there is data in the "start" range.
    Do While findRng.Text <> vbNullString          'Do while there is data in the "find" range.
        With Worksheets("Formatting").Range("FormattingTable[" & findTableColumn & "]")
            Set c = .Find(findRng.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                    firstAddress = c.Address
                    Do
                        If handledBool = True Then
                            If c.Offset(0, handledOffset).Text <> vbNullString Then
                                If c.Offset(0, startOffset).Text = startRng.Text Then
                                    x = x + 1
                                End If
                            End If
                        Else
                            If c.Offset(0, startOffset).Text = startRng.Text Then
                                x = x + 1
                            End If
                        End If
                    Set c = .FindNext(c)
                    Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
        End With
'==========================================================================
'==========================================================================
        If firstLoop = True Then   'If this is the first time through loop then paste find items
            pasteFindRng.Value = findRng.Text
            Set pasteFindRng = pasteFindRng.Offset(1, 0) 'Set pastefind range down 1
        End If
'==========================================================================
        pasteAccum.Value = x                  'Set x to paste.
        Set pasteAccum = pasteAccum.Offset(1, 0)    'Set accumulator paste range down 1.
        x = 0                                       'Reset x
'==========================================================================
        Set findRng = findRng.Offset(1, 0)          'Set find range down 1.
'==========================================================================
    Loop
    If firstLoop = True Then 'If this is the first time through loop then paste the title.
        pasteStartRng.Offset(0, -1) = strTitle
    End I
'==========================================================================
    pasteStartRng.Value = startRng.Text             'Paste the value of the start range.
'==========================================================================
    Set pasteStartRng = pasteStartRng.Offset(0, 1)   'Set paste start range over to the right 1.
'==========================================================================
    Set pasteAccum = pasteStartRng.Offset(1, 0)     'Reset "accumulator" paste range.
'==========================================================================
    Set startRng = startRng.Offset(1, 0)            'Move "start" range down 1.
    Set findRng = initialFindRng                    'Reset "find" range.
'==========================================================================
    firstLoop = False
Loop
'========================================================================================
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Any reason you won't just use SUMIFS or DSUM or any of the other built-in mechanisms for this sort of thing?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H4YRPdRXKFs

Comment: Thank you. I'll check those functions out. I've done some research on that before and didn't find anything built in that counts the occurrences of different strings in multiple columns in the same row but I could be wrong! SumIF looks like it might be a contender. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As a tip, try to create a variable with

```
Range("FormattingTable[" & findTableColumn & "]")
```

value and avoid to do this inside a loop. Or better replace:

```
Worksheets("Formatting").Range("FormattingTable[" & findTableColumn & "]")
```

by a range value inside a loop.